# javascript:void(0) too long (shorter way)

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I know this is a dumb question 
but is there a shorter way of writing

`javascript:void(0)` for anchor links?

example :

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="functionHere()"> Click me </a>`

I don't like to use `"#"` because clicking the link brings me to the top of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter version is:

```
<a href="javascript:;" ...>
```

Comment: This is really not advised. Using inline javascript triggers `eval`.

Answer (score 4):

Even due there is an answer allready selected, 
i wanted to contribute my opinion on this.

using an href with a `javascript:;` `javascript:void(0);` `javascript:return false;` is bad practice search engine's will try to crawl your href and will find a broken link.

that being said, i do understand that sometimes you do need a link that follows nowhere, but executes something on the page.

i would have done it this way:

```
<script>
var elm = document.getElementById('myElement'); 
elm.style.cursor = 'pointer'; 
elm.onclick = function() { 
    // do something... 
}; 

</script>

<span id="myElement">Click Here</span>
```

this way, you html code stays clean and nice.
please dont look at this as "Good Coding", since you allways need to keep a version for browsers with javascript disabled (yes, yes, i know that 99% will have it enabled ),
But if evil must be done, may it be the less evil possible at least.

Comment: +1: I don't even agree this wouldn't be "Good Coding": If Javascript isn't enabled, the original solution wouldn't work anyway. Also from a semantic point of view, it would be the cleanest way *not*  to use a "link" element if you don't want to link anything. The only suggestion I'd make is to use a `<span>` instead of a `<div>`, since this comes closer to the original `<a>` Tag ...

Comment: +1 for the `<span>` tag, updated the code. if javascript is not enabled, the user should get a page with the content i guess should popup with JS. that is why i dont consider it "Good Coding" since if JS is disabled, the whole thing breaks and wont work.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do that:

```
<style type="text/css">
.pointer{
  cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
<a class="pointer" onclick="functionHere()"> Click me </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<a href="#" onClick="return false;"> Click me </a>
```

Comment: +1: or to stay with the original question: `onClick="functionHere(); return false;"` ...

Comment: +1 = I like your solution :) And in the question, a click to the link called the "functionHere" function. So in order to get the same result without changing the function, you could extend your solution with `onClick="functionHere(); return false;"` and have the same result as before (the function is called) without jumping to the top of the page.

Answer (score -2):

```
function a() {};

<a href="javascript:a();">
<a href="javascript://">
<a href="don't_load" onclick="doit();return false;">
```

Comment: i did not vote you down, but i understand why you were voted down. even due your answer does work, it is really bad practice.